# How to join two recordset created from two different data source in excel vba

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

My Scenario is -
I have one set of data in .xls file and another set of data in oracle data base table. I want import both data using excel vba then perform join (sql like) and finally save the data in some workbook.

Problem -
I do not know how to get two different set of data in vba and then perform join.
In .Net there is DataSet object where we can save the imported data and then perform any query on it but vba How I can do this?

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524214-visual-basic-applications-joining-multiple-recordets-multiple-databases.html plenty of google answers on this.

Comment: Thank You MatthewD, but how can I perform sql like join? I did not understand as provided in your link.

Comment: Here is another that is a bit more sql like. But you may have to do some work and not just a single statement.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bee47e0a-2a73-4653-aa10-78e1f03cc4e2/need-to-do-left-join-between-two-recordsets

Comment: If you place both sets of data in Excel you can use SQL to perform the join on the two tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304563/how-to-use-sql-joins-in-excel

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay Do both of your sets of data have exactly the same fields? What is your Excel version, 2003 or later, 32-bit / 64-bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the below example using ADO. The code allows to get data from several data sources within single SQL query (Jet SQL), particularly make unions from `.xlsx` files, and put result recordset to the worksheet. Unfortunately I have no available Oracle data source to test, though you can connect directly to Oracle also with ADO (like any other database) via [Oracle ODBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html).

The code is placed in `Query.xlsm`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SqlUnionTest()

    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object

    strConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"

    strQuery = _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source1.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source2.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source3.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "ORDER BY ContactName;"

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
    RecordSetToWorksheet Sheets(1), objRecordSet
    objConnection.Close

End Sub

Sub RecordSetToWorksheet(objSheet As Worksheet, objRecordSet As Object)

    Dim i As Long

    With objSheet
        .Cells.Delete
        For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Note, `ThisWorkbook.Path` should not contain `'` within path. Otherwise you have to escape them by replacing `'` with `''`.

Also there are three [data source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) files in the same folder as `Query.xlsm`.

`Source1.xlsx`:

[image: Source1.xlsx]

`Source2.xlsx`:

[image: Source2.xlsx]

`Source3.xlsx`:

[image: Source3.xlsx]

The resulting worksheet is as follows:

[image: Query.xlsm result]

It works on 64-bit version Excel 2013 for me. To make it compatible with `.xls` and Excel 2003 (where the provider `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` isn't installed) you have to replace `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` with `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;`, and also in extended properties `Excel 12.0 Macro;` / `Excel 12.0;` with `Excel 8.0;`. You can easily add `WHERE` clause and other SQL stuff to the query. Actually data source for connection object isn't limited the only `Query.xlsm` file, which the code placed in. It could be another data source, compatible with one of the available providers, either file-based or server-based. Find more connection strings for your data source on http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Consider beginning your answer with the strategy used: VBA ADO connection. And even suggest that OP can connect directly to Oracle also with ADO (like any other database) using [Oracle ODBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html).

Comment: Thanks for your example.

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay please click to accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: @omegastripes sorry for commenting on an old post, but cudnt find any docs for such a SELECT statement. What i want to know is if i replace the excel files with 2 csv files located in different folders, can i JOIN them together? Right now i am getting a SYNTAX error. I am not using `ODBC MICROSOFT ACCESS TEXT DRIVER` as i see it cannot handle spaces in paths. I can share the code as a new post. Please advice.