# Recordset Query - Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

```
strQuery = _
    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source1.xlsx' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
    "UNION " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source2.xlsx' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
    "UNION " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source3.xlsx' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
    "ORDER BY A;"
```

Hi,

I have the above inside a Module in VBA (the code itself is [sourced from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376642/445425) ). My question is, my columns in each file starts from row 15 and data goes down from row 16. How do I make it so that each file, it would look to UNION from row 15?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in the first 15 rows? Are the headers in row 1, or row 15?

Comment: Headers on row 15 - First 14 have some KPIs regarding the data below (standard for every file)

Comment: AFAIK to query Excel worksheets like this they need to be formatted as data tables, i.e. with column headings in row 1 and the data starting in row 2, and consistent data types throughout a column; these 14 rows of KPIs are possibly going to throw off column type inference. I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Depending on what comes in the intervening rows, you could set the HDR property in the connection string to `NO`, and add a WHERE clause that would catch the rows above the header. It would mainly depend on the structure of the header and the data though.

Comment: Could you kindly help me out with the where clause?

I've used it in the context of column...eg: Where [Customer Name] = "Max"

But to capture 14 rows using where is bit confusing! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Excel workbook SQL queries via ADO or DAO, you can specify the regions of a worksheet by setting a range in the fashion: `[Sheet$A1:Z2]`. First find the last named column (recall for `UNION` they must be same lengths and types) and add rows sufficient for valid querying. Below uses *Z999*:

```vb
strQuery = _
    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:Z999] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source1.xlsx' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
    "UNION " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:Z999] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source2.xlsx' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
    "UNION " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:Z999] " & _
    "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source3.xlsx' " & _
    "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "ORDER BY A;"
```

Comment: Appreciate your help :)