# Connecting to several data sources from Excel via VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ado

Trying to connect to different data sources (VFP database and Access file) from inside Excel to extract specific data, based on the criteria from both sources and encountered problem of creating a combined query. The query to VFP table is already completed and now I need to address MS Access table.
I've tried to do it the following way, but no success:

```
"left join [tblInAccess] in " & "[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source='D:\Data\temp_dump.accdb'] on [tblInVFP].ID=[tblInAccess].ID"
```

Can anyone point to correct syntax?

**UPD**:
Whole query code (just query):

```
SELECT DB.DATE AS DBF_DATE,
    DB.EN AS DBF_EN,
    DB.NU AS DBF_NUMERO,
    LIB.LL AS DBF_LIBELLE,
    SUM(IIF(DB.DEBIT = '1000', - DB.AMOUNT, 0.00) + IIF(DB.CREDIT = '1000', DB.AMOUNT, 0.00))
FROM [VFP_DB] AS DB
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT LT.LL AS LL,
        LT.EN
    FROM [VFP_DB] AS LT
    ) AS LIB ON DB.EN = LIB.EN
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM [Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="D:\Data\temp_dump.accdb";].[tblTemp]
    ) TEMP_DB ON DB.NN = TEMP_DB.id
WHERE DB.DATE >= { ^ 2015.12 .30 }
    AND DB.DATE <= { ^ 2017.01 .07 }
    AND TEMP_DB.id IS NULL
GROUP BY DB.DATE,
    DB.NU,
    DB.EN,
    LIB.LL
HAVING SUM(IIF(DB.DEBIT = '1000', - DB.AMOUNT, 0.00) + IIF(DB.CREDIT = '1000', DB.AMOUNT, 0.00)) <> 0
ORDER BY DB.DATE,
    DB.NU,
    DB.EN ASC
```

Actually, without the 2nd 'Left join' it's working correctly. Problems appeared when I tried to reference Access database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While it is not my domain, I think you are only having part of the query. It will be helpful to have the whole query and also the error you got.

Comment: What @ZiyanJunaideen said, + you also need to share your code executing the query. That's all relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have are executing the query on an Access database, you don't need to specify the database type, only the location:

```sql
LEFT JOIN [tblInAccess] in D:\Data\temp_dump.accdb on [tblInVFP].ID=[tblInAccess].ID
```

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for further details.

Also note: `{ ^ 2015.12 .30 }` will likely cause a syntax error in Access. If you want to filter by a date, the proper syntax is `#2015/12/30#` to define a date constant.

Comment: Erik, thanks for dedicating some of your time to my problem! The thing is that the entire query is passed to a VisualFoxPro database from EXCEL via ADO and not to MS Access. But I wanted to make ADO understand that some of the data are to be taken from a temporary Access table. So I was searching the way to reference Access db file with it's driver inside a query (Possibly there is another way to do it - I don't know). Concerning dates format: this format is required by VFP database and it's correct in this case

Comment: Similar question has been posted previously already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294382/how-to-join-two-recordset-created-from-two-different-data-source-in-excel-vba), but it's connected with Excel. In my case I need just to build a valid Access connection string instead