# One RecordSet with multiple Connections & SQL Querys

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I have a VBA application that calls several sheets and obtains a set of data for each of them. All the information obtained must end in a single variant matrix.

I have thought of several solutions. These are:

1. The first of them, join the recordsets to get one only.
2. The second one would be to sequentially dump each of the RecordSets in
   the single matrix

Both solutions do not seem to be the solution ...
This is the code for solution number 1:

```
Sub Test()
Dim RS01 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim RS02 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Query As String
Dim FField As Variant
Dim Pair As Variant
Dim Pairs As Variant
Dim MFTE() As Variant
Dim Temp() As Variant
Dim Rows As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim Column As Long
Dim Connection As String
'Looping throught the pairs
Pairs() = Array("EURAUD", "EURCAD")
For Each Pair In Pairs
    Select Case Par
        Case "EURAUD"
            Query = _
                "SELECT [FE], [HO], [AP], [MAX], [MIN], [CIE], [PAR]" & _
                "FROM [EURAUD$]" & _
                "WHERE (FE >=" & Date1 & ") and (FE <=" & Date2 & ")"
            Connection = _
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=File Number 1;" & _
                "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
            Set RS01 = New ADODB.Recordset
            RS01.Open Query, Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
        Case "EURCAD"
            Query = _
                "SELECT [FE], [HO], [AP], [MAX], [MIN], [CIE], [PAR]" & _
                "FROM [EURCAD$]" & _
                "WHERE (FE >=" & Date1 & ") and (FE <=" & Date2 & ")"
            Connection = _
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=File Number 2;" & _
                "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
            Set RS02 = New ADODB.Recordset
            RS02.Open Query, Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
    End Select
Next Pair
'Joining RS01 & RS02
RS01.MoveFirst
Do Until RS01.EOF
    RS02.AddNew
    For FField = 0 To RS01.Fields.Count - 1
        RS02.Fields(FField).Value = RS01.Fields(FField).Value
    Next FField
    RS02.Update
    RS01.MoveNext
Loop
'Dumping data into 1st variant Array
Do Until RS07.EOF
    Temp() = RS07.GetRows
Loop
'Transpose data into 2nd variant Array
Rows = RS07.RecordCount
ReDim MFTE(Rows, 7) As Variant
For Row = LBound(Temp, 2) To UBound(Temp, 2)
    For Column = LBound(Temp, 1) To UBound(Temp, 1)
        MFTE(Row, Column) = Temp(Column, Row)
    Next Column
Next Row
End Sub
```

With this solution I have some problems:

1. The final RecordSet has a mix from the 1st and 2nd RecordSets
2. The 1st variant array needs to be transposed

So, is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you just use CopyFromRecordset and dump all results on a temporary tab in Excel using this method: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tmp_sheet"t).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS01

Comment: Or maybe build a unique UNION sql that consolidates all your queries? (supposing they have the same fields) sFinalSQL=Query1 & " UNION " & Query2

Comment: MR, CopyFromRecorset solution implicates write and read from the sheet, slow downing the process

Comment: Build a unique UNION seems a better solution, anyway consider that there are multiple sources and yes they have the same fields, but I don't know do it. How would you do it?

Comment: Quite right, UNION would not work because of multiple data sources. Please find my answer below.

Comment: M.R. Thanks a lot for your time I appreciate it.. Talking about UNION solution, would be possible join the query as omegastripes does in this post?: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294382/how-to-join-two-recordset-created-from-two-different-data-source-in-excel-vba)

Comment: MR: and also, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Interesting... yes I think it should work. You have to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 providder (32 or 64-bit) on your machine. Please post the result!

Comment: An important point: use "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro" if your file is an XLSM and "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml" if the file is an XLSX

Comment: Hi M.R.: I'm going to try this solution...give me a couple of days or so...and I'll tell you how it works....Thanks a lot M.R.

Comment: Hi M.R. I tried 4 different solutions: a) build an UNION Query, b) join each RecordSets from each connection, c) join each array from each RecordSet and finally CopyFromRecordSet method. And in my opinion the last one is the best one. You were right, its enought quick. Congratulations and many, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still recommend "CopyFromRecordset", there is some coding involved but I don't think the process will be significantly slowed down, maybe a fraction of a second