# Can't union two tables even though ADODB confirms equal field counts

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I'm not able to union two csvs even though ADODB confirms via `.Fields.Count` that they both have the same number of columns.

Here's the query that's failing:

`select * from csv1.csv union select * from csv2.csv`

with the error message:

> The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union query do not match

However, when I do `select * from csv1.csv` and `select * from csv2.csv` separately, ADODB confirms that .Fields.Count = 8 for both.

**Possible key to the problem:**

Do I need to create two separate connections? I'm only creating one connection (to the first csv) even though there are two csvs in the query.

I was trying to figure out how to do two separate connections for the same query and it seemed like people weren't finding that necessary - I couldn't find two connections mentioned in equivalent queries people were running against csvs.

---

Per @Parfait's request to see more of the code:

**GetDataFromCSV**

```
Public Function GetDataFromCSV(ByVal fileReport As Scripting.File, ByVal strQuery As String, ByVal arrSourceReports As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim strRevisedQuery As String
    strRevisedQuery = GetRevisedQueryWithFileAliasesReplacedWithTrueFileNames(strQuery, arrSourceReports)

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = OpenConnectionToCSV(fileReport)
    If cnn Is Nothing Then
        GetDataFromCSV = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetDataFromCSV = QueryDataFromCSV(cnn, strRevisedQuery, fileReport.Name, fileReport.Name)

End Function
```

**OpenConnectionToCSV**

```
Private Function OpenConnectionToCSV(ByVal fileCSV As Scripting.File, Optional boolHeadersPresent As Boolean = True) As ADODB.Connection

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.ConnectionTimeout = 0

    Dim strfileCSVParentFolderPath As String
    strfileCSVParentFolderPath = fileCSV.ParentFolder
    If Right(strfileCSVParentFolderPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then strfileCSVParentFolderPath = strfileCSVParentFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator

    Dim strConn As String
    If boolHeadersPresent = False Then
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & strfileCSVParentFolderPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""
    Else
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & strfileCSVParentFolderPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
    End If

    If strConn <> vbNullString Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Dim lngRetryCount As Long
        lngRetryCount = 0
        cnn.Open strConn
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OpenConnectionToCSV = cnn
    End If

    Exit Function


ErrorHandler:
    Select Case True
        Case InStr(1, Err.Description, "Connect timeout occurred", vbTextCompare) > 0
            If lngRetryCount < 30 Then
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                lngRetryCount = lngRetryCount + 1
                Resume
            Else
                MsgBox "Can't connect to " & fileCSV.Path & ". Reading this file will be skipped."
                Exit Function
            End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Getting data from " & fileCSV.Name & " has failed with the following error message: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            On Error GoTo 0
            Resume
    End Select

End Function
```

**QueryDataFromCSV**

```
Private Function QueryDataFromCSV(ByVal cnn As ADODB.Connection, ByVal strQuery As String, ByVal strCSVName As String, ByVal strFinalReportTitle As String) As Boolean

    QueryDataFromCSV = True

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = PrepareQueryCommand(cnn, strQuery)
    CreateQueryDebugLog cmd.CommandText

    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open cmd

    Dim Loop1 As Long
    With rst
        For Loop1 = 1 To .Fields.Count
            If .Fields(Loop1 - 1).Name = "F" & Loop1 Then
                If Loop1 < 4 Then
                    MsgBox "Can't retrieve data from " & strCSVName & " because it is formatted improperly."
                Else
                    MsgBox "Can't retrieve data from " & strCSVName & " because it is delimited improperly. The file is most likely delimited with a comma even though it has addresses or other fields that contain commas. Ask Encounters IT to change this report's delimiter to another character, such as | (pipe), in the Tidal batch file."
                End If

                QueryDataFromCSV = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next Loop1
    End With

    CopyThisCSVRecordsetToResultSheets rst, strFinalReportTitle
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Function
```

> The error is occurring at `rst.Open cmd` in the above function `QueryDataFromCSV`

---

Illustrating schema.ini creation for @Comintern:

**GetRevisedQueryWithFileAliasesReplacedWithTrueFileNames**

```
Private Function GetRevisedQueryWithFileAliasesReplacedWithTrueFileNames(ByVal strQuery As String, ByVal arrSourceReports As Variant) As String

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim lngPosition As Long
    lngPosition = 0

    Do Until lngPosition > Len(strQuery)
        Dim lngStartPosition As Long
        lngStartPosition = InStr(lngPosition + 1, strQuery, "from", vbTextCompare) + 5
        If lngStartPosition > lngPosition Then
            Dim lngEndPosition As Long
            lngEndPosition = InStr(lngStartPosition + 1, strQuery, " ", vbTextCompare)
            If lngEndPosition = 0 Then lngEndPosition = Len(strQuery) + 1

            Dim strSourceReportTitle As String
            strSourceReportTitle = Mid(strQuery, lngStartPosition, lngEndPosition - lngStartPosition)

            Dim Loop2 As Long
            For Loop2 = LBound(arrSourceReports, 1) To UBound(arrSourceReports, 1)
                If arrSourceReports(Loop2, 1) = strSourceReportTitle Then Exit For
            Next Loop2

            Dim fileSource As Scripting.File
            Set fileSource = FSO.GetFile(arrSourceReports(Loop2, 3))

            If arrSourceReports(Loop2, 2) = "TAB" Then arrSourceReports(Loop2, 2) = Chr(9)
            CreateSchemaIni fileSource, arrSourceReports(Loop2, 2)

            Dim strRevisedQuery As String
            If strRevisedQuery = vbNullString Then
                strRevisedQuery = Replace(strQuery, "from " & strSourceReportTitle, "from " & fileSource.Name)
            Else
                strRevisedQuery = Replace(strRevisedQuery, "from " & strSourceReportTitle, "from " & fileSource.Name)
            End If

            lngPosition = lngEndPosition
        Else
            lngPosition = Len(strQuery) + 1
        End If
    Loop

    GetRevisedQueryWithFileAliasesReplacedWithTrueFileNames = strRevisedQuery

End Function
```

**CreateSchemaIni**

```
Private Sub CreateSchemaIni(ByVal fileReport As Scripting.File, ByVal strDelimiter As String)

    Dim intSystemFileNumber As Integer
    intSystemFileNumber = FreeFile()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Open fileReport.ParentFolder.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Schema.ini" For Output As #intSystemFileNumber
    Print #intSystemFileNumber, "[" & fileReport.Name & "]"
    Print #intSystemFileNumber, "Format=Delimited(" & strDelimiter & ")"
    Close #intSystemFileNumber

    Exit Sub


ErrorHandler:
    Select Case True
        Case InStr(1, Err.Description, "Path/File Access Error", vbTextCompare) > 0
            Dim strStandardQueryDebugLogPath As String
            strStandardQueryDebugLogPath = fileReport.ParentFolder.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "strQuery.txt"
            MsgBox strStandardQueryDebugLogPath & " was inaccessible. Creating log in same folder where your copy of the Mass Queryer is saved instead."
            Open Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, Application.PathSeparator, , vbTextCompare)) & "strQuery.txt" For Output As #intSystemFileNumber
            Print #intSystemFileNumber, "[" & fileReport.Name & "]"
            Print #intSystemFileNumber, "Format=Delimited(" & strDelimiter & ")"
            Close #intSystemFileNumber
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Creating a query debug log has failed with the following error message: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            On Error GoTo 0
            Resume
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What driver are you using? Are you specifying the column data types, or is the provider handling that for you?

Comment: Please post the full code block and not line snippets, so we can see connection, driver, query call, etc.

Comment: @Comintern Does `Microsoft Active Data Objects 6.0 Library answer the driver question? I'm not specifying the column data types - should I?

Comment: @Parfait Sure, give me a few minutes to get all the blocks up... It's going to be a lot.

Comment: No, I'm more interested in the connection string. If you have a column *type* mismatch, that could explain the UNION failing.

Comment: All blocks? A lot? An ADO connection in VBA with SQL and recordset call should not be but few lines. Please remember the M in [MCVE].

Comment: Is it possible to to go after the fields like `SELECT f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8 FROM...` To insure they are the same. If it's still giving problems then you could consider adding a `Cast(f1 as whatevermakessense)` around each field to insure the number and types line up for the union.

Comment: @Parfait code posted

Comment: @Comintern Here's my connection string: `strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & strfileCSVParentFolderPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""`

Comment: @JNevill Running out to lunch but I'll try this as soon as I get back.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 There is no need to create two separate connections, you may connect to the workbook like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376642/2165759).

Comment: Based on your connection, I'm guessing you just need a [schema.ini file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @Comintern You are exactly right. I posted the code you need to prove that for your answer. You can see above on the `CreateSchemaIni fileSource, arrSourceReports(Loop2, 2)` line and the relevant sub that I'm creating and then overwriting rather than creating and then appending for each file. If you post this answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It is not that easy to use datasheets as tables since many unprecedented problems occur when we run it or when we update the files 1-I would check if you have any used column that is maybe picked by your SQL execution, 2- `SELECT *` usually considers everything as `string`, however ADO uses the first 8 rows to determine the type of the fields, it is better to explicitly define the data types, this would cause a problem when you have numeric and text data in one of the columns

Comment: and you cannot run SQL queries on recordsets coming from 2 different connections, SQL queries must happen inside one connection, if that is the issue then you have to first convert the csv data to a SQL table and then run the query under one single connection

Comment: Have you tried powerquery? Combine queries to union files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Comintern's help, I was able to see that I made a silly mistake having nothing to do with the question title in actuality. You can see above that my `CreateSchemaIni` method was creating and then overwriting the `Schema.ini` file for each csv I was querying rather than creating and then appending to it. By changing that method to use `Open For Append` instead of `Open For Output`, the problem was solved.