# Record Macro: Get Data from File

Tags: excel, vba, get, record

I'll start by admitting Macro's are generally not my thing and writing the code certainly isn't - but in the situation and having read about recording macros i thought it could work for me. If this isn't the way to do it feel free to say so and i will dismiss the idea for the time being until i can do more research and write the code.

Essentially the steps I'm trying to achieve
- Starting from a blank workbook
- Use macro to get data from a folder in our company network containing about 15 workbooks which all have the same internal format and information but relate to different geographic locations
- I recorded the macro using exactly the steps i use if i were doing the task manually which i know works fine

the full code text is below. Upon running i immediately get a run-time error which when debugged highlights the first section and states "A query with the name 'Pipeline Working' already exists. "Pipeline Working" is the name of the folder in which contains the workbooks to import, from there I'm already lost.

Any help appreciated.

```
Sub PipelinePredictions()
'
' PipelinePredictions Macro
' Import Data from File for Pipeline Predictions
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Pipeline Working", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""\\hofileserver\Accounts\ACCOUNTS\Lettings Stats 2018 Qtr 4\Pipelines\Pipeline Working"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Hidden Files1"" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Invoke Custom Function1"" = Table.AddColumn(#""Filtered Hidden Files1"", ""Transform File from Pipeline Working"", each #""Transform File f" & _
        "rom Pipeline Working""([Content]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns1"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Invoke Custom Function1"", {""Name"", ""Source.Name""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Other Columns1"" = Table.SelectColumns(#""Renamed Columns1"", {""Source.Name"", ""Transform File from Pipeline Working""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Table Column1"" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#""Removed Other Columns" & _
        "1"", ""Transform File from Pipeline Working"", Table.ColumnNames(#""Transform File from Pipeline Working""(#""Sample File"")))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Expanded Table Column1"",{{""Source.Name"", type text}, {""Column1"", type any}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type number}" & _
        ", {""Column6"", Percentage.Type}, {""Column7"", Int64.Type}, {""Column8"", type number}, {""Column9"", type number}, {""Column10"", type number}, {""Column11"", type any}, {""Column12"", type datetime}, {""Column13"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Changed Type"",{{""Source.Name"", ""Branch""}, {""Column1"", ""Week Booked""}, {""Col" & _
        "umn2"", ""Neg""}, {""Column3"", ""Property""}, {""Column4"", ""Service Type""}, {""Column5"", ""Rent""}, {""Column6"", ""Percentage Fee""}, {""Column7"", ""Term""}, {""Column8"", ""Fee""}, {""Column9"", ""Admin""}, {""Column10"", ""Total Fees""}, {""Column11"", ""Rent G'tee""}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type1"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Renamed Columns"",{{""Column12" & _
        """, type date}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns2"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Changed Type1"",{{""Column12"", ""Move in Date""}, {""Column13"", ""Notes""}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns2"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sample File Parameter1", Formula:= _
        "#""Sample File"" meta [IsParameterQuery=true, BinaryIdentifier=#""Sample File"", Type=""Binary"", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _
        "Transform Sample File from Pipeline Working", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(#""Sample File Parameter1"", null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""'A Pipeline$'Print_Area1"" = Source{[Name=""'A Pipeline$'Print_Area""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""'A Pipeline$'Print_Area1"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sample File", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""\\hofileserver\Accounts\ACCOUNTS\Lettings Stats 2018 Qtr 4\Pipelines\Pipeline Working"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Navigation1 = Source{0}[Content]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Navigation1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Transform File from Pipeline Working", _
        Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = (#""Sample File Parameter1"") => let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        Source = Excel.Workbook(#""Sample File Parameter1"", null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        #""'A Pipeline$'Print_Area1"" = Source{[Name=""'A Pipeline$'Print_Area""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        #""'A Pipeline$'Print_Area1""" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Pipeline Working"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Pipeline Working]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_ExternalData_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "Query - Sample File Parameter11", _
        "Connection to the 'Sample File Parameter1' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Sample File Parameter1"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , "SELECT * FROM [Sample File Parameter1]", 2
    Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 _
        "Query - Transform Sample File from Pipeline Working1", _
        "Connection to the 'Transform Sample File from Pipeline Working' query in the workbook." _
        , Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Transform Sample File from Pipeline Working"";Extended Propert" _
        , "ies="""""), "SELECT * FROM [Transform Sample File from Pipeline Working]", 2
    Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "Query - Sample File1", _
        "Connection to the 'Sample File' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Sample File"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , "SELECT * FROM [Sample File]", 2
    Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 _
        "Query - Transform File from Pipeline Working1", _
        "Connection to the 'Transform File from Pipeline Working' query in the workbook." _
        , _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Transform File from Pipeline Working"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , "SELECT * FROM [Transform File from Pipeline Working]", 2
    Windows("Book3").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you just want to open each file in the folder "Pipeline Working" and import the data from the same range in each into your staring workbook? Into separate pages or one big table?

Comment: The macro recorder found an interesting way but you want a practical one. Just open each file in the folder, copy some data from it and paste it into your master. Repeat with each one. If you google for this kind of code you will find many examples on the web. They will give you a better start than the macro recorder.

Comment: @HarassedDad To question one yes and to question 2 just one big table which i will then analyse from.To expand Q1 i also only want to select data from a pre-set Print Area which the get data function allows

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376642/2165759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This opens all workbooks in folder and copies the range called print area into the current spreadsheet - it assumes this code is in a blank workbook

```
Sub ImportData()
 Const FolderToImport = "C:\Pipeline Working\" 'adjust as suits - keep last \ at end
 Dim s As String
 s = Dir(FolderToImport & "*.xl??")
 Do While s <> ""
       Dim wb As Workbook
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderToImport & s, False, True)
       wb.Sheets(1).Range("print area").Copy Destination:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       wb.Close False
       s = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I get error 1004 from this point - wb.Sheets(1).Range("print area").Copy Destination:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) - is there anything i need to amend?

Comment: The code assumes there's a range called Print Area in each file - you'll get that error if there isn't - you may need to change it to an explicit range by address: wb.sheets(1).range("a1:c22") or similar

Comment: Thank you again. I've just verified that my sheet does have a print area set and just tried a single sheet as a test however I'm getting the same error. Instead of the print area i tried the range suggestion as above which worked perfectly however not all my sheets will have an identical range. Whilst i could attempt to define a more specific range i would prefer not to and the print area is the perfect solution if possible please